# how to smooth jagged edges?

Tags: modeling

Please see attached picture.  Blender seems to have trouble with curves.  Even after applying "shade smooth" or "line by crease" from MeasureItArch, the curves still appear jagged.[image]

I originally thought it had to do with imported WRL files, but I had a similar issue with a cylindrical shape created in Blender, too.  Is there a good way to smooth these curves out?  Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to use the Subdivision Surface modifier?

Answer (score 3):

This is entirely normal.

You can turn up the resolution of the curve in the Properties editor.

Explanation: In CG, all surfaces are secretly made up of flat pieces. The trick is to get enough of them that you don’t notice. Shade Smooth fakes the way light interacts with the surface into looking more smoothed, but does not alter the geometry. If you 3D printed a model in two versions, one shaded smooth and the other shaded flat, they would come out the exact same way.

Comment: Noted.  Thank you!